# Live Backup using Proxmox's snapshot-drive command

Tags: backup, snapshot, qemu, proxmox

I have a KVM server(not on a proxmox node), my VPS is based on qcow2 format and I would like to do a live backup of the vms.
I have understood there are two types of backup, Internal and External, I have found while testing that the internal backup stops the vm for a millisecond and external one will create a new file. Is it that the later versions of Qemu does not do this anymore(stopping the vps)?, Please let me know if that's the case, Or if there is any command which does a live backup without stopping the vps, I have been using *virsh snapshot-create*.

Anyway, after some more research I came across the Proxmox's backup feature and I saw that it uses some "*qmp snapshot-drive*" command. 
I have been trying to get some more details on this particular command online but in vain. I would like to know about this command since it does not shut down or pause the VM and does not create an external snapshot file, your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can do this if it's not a Proxmox server. The image format has to be qcow2, which you have. The underlying storage must support snapshots as well.

See the requirements section of the Proxmox docs [here](http://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Live_Snapshots)